# Is there a way to animate images when you hover over the div they are in instead of the individual images with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to animate two images within my #header div.  Currently, when you hover over the individual images, they move to their respective positions.  But I want to move my first image down and my second image up at the same time - when hovering over the #header div.

```css
.set {
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
    transition: top ease 0.5s;
}

.set:hover{
    top: 15px;
}

.rise {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    transition: top ease 0.5s;
}

.rise:hover {
  top: -15px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="header">
        <header>
            <h1>My Title!</h1>
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/71/ba/35/71ba3562bc89f6a11e5d5625da09bfeb.png" alt="sun" width="100px" class="set">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/z6PQ7qX/moon.png" alt="moon" width="100px" class="rise">
        </header>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try using css keyframes for each image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to group both images together in element, and offset the images when that wrapper-element is hovered over. And when hovering over an individual image, override that offset.

That way, everything that is not hovered over, is being offset the opposite way.

**Sidenote:**
I removed the classes as well as the `<div id="header">`-tag. Reason is, the images can be selected quite easily even without a class, and secondly, because there is already an element purposed as a header semantically.

The `display: flex; flex-flow: column;` on `<header>` and the `align-self: flex-start` on `<div>` are to keep the layout-flow vertically and the `<div>` at minimum size.
Without the `align-self: flex-start`, the `<div>` would stretch out, filling the rest of the row (basically `width: 100%`), which would result in unwanted behavior when hovering over it.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow:column;
}
header > div {align-self: flex-start}
header > div > img {
  width: 100px;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
header > div:hover > img {transform: translateY(-15px)}
header > div:hover > img:hover {transform: translateY(15px)}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>My Title!</h1>
  <div>
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/71/ba/35/71ba3562bc89f6a11e5d5625da09bfeb.png" alt="Sun">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/z6PQ7qX/moon.png" alt="Moon">
  </div>
</header>
```